# Remove metaData node from xml

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

This is my xml ouput which i m working

```
   <adamContent projectTypeID="10" genContentID="000002">
        <metaData>
            <keywordList>
                      <keyword>
                            <word>#27</word>
                            <relevancy>120</relevancy>
                      </keyword>
                      <keyword>
                            <word>#43</word>
                            <relevancy>114</relevancy>
                      </keyword>
             </keywordList>
            <taxonomy type="CPT">
               <code>99374</code>
            </taxonomy>
        </metaData>
         <textContent title="Description" ordinal="0" group="0">
             <p>An in-depth report on the causes, diagnosis, and treatment of Alzheimer's disease.</p>
        </textContent>
</adamContent>
```

and i need output like that(**i want to remove whole metaData node**)

```
<adamContent projectTypeID="10" genContentID="000002">
         <textContent title="Description" ordinal="0" group="0">
             <p>An in-depth report on the causes, diagnosis, and treatment of Alzheimer's disease.</p>
        </textContent>
</adamContent>
```

this is my php code wht i try so far

```
<?php
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$atvID =   $xmldoc->load('000002.xml', LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
foreach($atvID as $id){
    $delnode = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('metaData');
    $xmldoc->firstChild->removeChild($delnode->item($id));
}
$xmldoc->save('000002.xml');
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('000002.xml');
$metadatas = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('metaData');
foreach ($metadatas as $metadata) {
    $metadata->parentNode->removeChild($metadata);
}
$xmldoc->save('000002.xml');
```